# Yosemite: How to remove files in /.Trashes on a TC external disk?

Tags: osx-yosemite

I have extended my Time Capsule storage by adding an external disk to the TC USB port.  Everything looks good except I see that /.Trashes on this disk has 241 GB of data that I don't need.  How can I get rid of it?

I am comfortable using terminal and sudo, although I'm very rusty, but I have no clue of even how to access this TC external disk from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it.  All external disks appear under /Volumes in terminal.  I cd'd to the directory under there that held my 241 GB of unwanted data and used

rm -r *

to remove all of it.  Of course this "remove recursively" should be used with great caution.